# How to fix x-axis in R ChIPseeker dotplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am using the ChIPseeker R. library. I'm having trouble with the `dotplot` function. I can't fix the x-axis.
As you can see from the image, the labels and the dotplot are not completely visible.
I guess using `xlim` parameter of `ggplot`, but it does not work, and in the documentation I have not found a parameter for this trivial problem.
if I use showCategory greater than 10 the chart auto-resizes itself in a worse way.

```
dotplot(x, showCategory=10)
```

[image: showCategory=10]

[image: showCategory=20]

Comment: Your y axis labels are simply too long. This is indeed a ggplot-based plot, and the actual plotting panel size is determined by how much space is left after the axis, legend and title are drawn. There is just no room for the plot because of how long your axis labels are. Try increasing the width of your plotting window or shortening the names of your y axis labels

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you show me how ?

Comment: Alessandro - I mean change the names in your data to make them shorter. I don't have your data because you didn't include it so I can't show you how.